# Amazon AWS EC2 Instance Not Connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to create and connect to an Amazon EC2 instance via FidOS.  I am following the procedure demonstrated in:

[How to Create Amazon AWS EC2 Instance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ce876F9soxA)

I logged onto the AWS Console and created a general purpose Ubuntu Server Machine image.
I configured the instance details, added storage, added tags, and configured the Security Group just as in the video.
I clicked "Review and Launch" and created and downloaded the PEM key.
I generated the PPK private key using PuttyGen.
I configured my session using the public DNS in the Host Name field and uploading the private PPK key in the Authorization tab.

After I clicked Open, a terminal window appeared, but then timed out.

I am working on a Windows machine, and trying to create a Ubuntu Linux virtual machine.

Am I missing any steps or doing anything wrong?  I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: check if the instance is reached on the ssh port, use `telnet <ip> <port>`

Comment: are you sure you have port 22 open on the security group? are you not on  a corporate network requiring proxy?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, all the ports are open.  The proxy may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the corporate firewall.  It worked just fine when I tried it from another location.